# How to add UINavigationController to UITabBar app's first view?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

This might not be exactly what you're thinking. I have a UITabBar app, with three tabs, all of which are linked to separate UIViews. On the first UIView (the default launch view) I have a search form. This view does not have a UINavigationController (as it's not wanted on this page).

When the user clicks search, I want to load a new view which has a UINavigationController (and still displays the Tab Bar at the bottom, with the first tab still highlighted).

From there, I want to just utilise the view as I normally would (which is out of the scope of this question so don't worry about that).

How would I go about doing this? I've seen some tutorials that suggest changing the class of the first view of the UITabBar from View Controller to Navigation Controller, but this adds the controller to the top of the first view (my search form) which isn't what I want :(.

Thanks in advance Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Panic over - I have found a nice solution:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

This hides the UINavigationController on the first view.